# Filtering a dataframe in python based on different columns condition

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have a dataframe in Python as shown below and I need to find the customers (Customer_ID) who trade the same category stuff and find if most of the relevant customers buy or sell the related category. Having done this, I should understand which of them are using Delivery, Download/Upload or both of them. It is important for me to avoid repetitive rows (e.g. customer_id of 40275 has three repeats on software category) which should count as one.
So, I need to classify the users with the same category, Delivery and Download/Upload without repetition.

| Customer_ID | Category | Type | Delivery | Download/Upload |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40275 | Book | Buy | True | True |
| 40275 | Software | Sell | False | True |
| 40275 | Software | Sell | False | True |
| 40275 | Software | Sell | False | True |
| 39900 | Confectionery recipe | Sell | True | True |
| 39900 | Book | Buy | True | True |
| 39900 | Software | Sell | True | True |
| 35886 | Book | Sell | False | True |
| 35886 | Book | Buy | False | True |
| 35886 | Confectionery recipe | Sell | False | True |
| 35886 | Software | Sell | False | True |
| 40350 | Software | Sell | True | True |
| 28129 | Software | Buy | False | True |
| 41571 | Software | Buy | True | True |

I have tried to get a subset of the main datafram based on the category fields but after that I was not sure how I can filter all of them at the same time, because there are some repetitive rows and some single rows. How should I solve this problem in Python?

The output I think should be something like this may be helpful. But I have not applied any filter on delivery or upload column:

| Customer_ID | Category | Type | Delivery | Download/Upload | counts of same category and type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40275 | Book | Buy | True | True | 2 |
| 40275 | Software | Sell | False | True | 4 |
| 39900 | Confectionery recipe | Sell | True | True | 2 |
| 39900 | Book | Buy | True | True | 2 |
| 39900 | Software | Sell | True | True | 4 |
| 35886 | Book | Sell | False | True | 1 |
| 35886 | Book | Buy | False | True | 2 |
| 35886 | Confectionery recipe | Sell | False | True | 2 |
| 35886 | Software | Sell | False | True | 4 |
| 40350 | Software | Sell | True | True | 4 |
| 28129 | Software | Buy | False | True | 2 |
| 41571 | Software | Buy | True | True | 2 |

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Shows us what you have tried and what should be the expected output.

Comment: If you aren't sure about what should be the expected output of your example then we can't be either, which makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: The current table sorta looks like `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), sort=False, as_index=False).size()`

Comment: @HarryPlotter,
Yes, you are right. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking something like this:

```
>>> df.drop_duplicates().assign(value=1) \
      .pivot(index=['Customer_ID', 'Category', 'Delivery', 'Download/Upload'], 
             columns='Type', values='value') \
      .fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()

Type  Customer_ID              Category  Delivery  Download/Upload  Buy  Sell
0           28129              Software     False             True    1     0
1           35886                  Book     False             True    1     1
2           35886  Confectionery recipe     False             True    0     1
3           35886              Software     False             True    0     1
4           39900                  Book      True             True    1     0
5           39900  Confectionery recipe      True             True    0     1
6           39900              Software      True             True    0     1
7           40275                  Book      True             True    1     0
8           40275              Software     False             True    0     1
9           40350              Software      True             True    0     1
10          41571              Software      True             True    1     0
```